# How to parse mysql_fetch_row into JSON object

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have the following code:

```
<?php 
include 'db.php';
$con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
$dbs = mysql_select_db($databaseName, $con);

$tableName = "tbl_title";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, fld_title FROM $tableName");

$data = array();
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_row($result) )
{
    //$data[] = $row;
    //$data['item'][] = $row;
    //$data['item'][] = $row['id'].value;
    $id = $row['id'];
    $fld_title = $row['fld_title'];
    $data = array( "id" => $id, "fld_title" => $fld_title);

    //echo $row['id'] . " " . $row['fld_title'];
            //echo '<option value="'.$row->id.'">'.$row->fld_title.'</option>'; 
}
echo json_encode( $data );  
    //  echo $row[0] . " " . $row[1];
?>
```

I am trying to return the results in a formatted way, however, even though I get results from the query, $id and $fld_title don't get set to a value.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no need to reference each column. `$row` is an array already. I've changed to using [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc) because that one gives named columns.

```
$data = array();
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) )
{
    $data[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode( $data );
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$data = array();
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_row($result) )
{
    $data[] = array( "id" => $row['id'] ,"fld_title" => $row['fld_title']);
}
var_dump(json_encode( $data ));
```

Updated

Get it by id:(I guess it unique)

```
 $data = array();
    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) )
    {
        $data[$row['id']] = array( "id" => $row['id'] ,"fld_title" => $row['fld_title']);
    }
    var_dump(json_encode( $data ));
```

Comment: lol fetch row gives only numerical array not associative array

Comment: Still not right `mysql_fetch_row` will return numerical key array not associative.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want this within the loop:

```
$data[] = array( "id" => $id, "fld_title" => $fld_title);
```

instead of:

```
$data = array( "id" => $id, "fld_title" => $fld_title);
```

So that one array per row is appended onto the output data array or you'll only output the last item.

Answer (score -1):

why fetching row when you can fetch `associative array` form the result directly so that you dont have to do extra coding to format the data.

**USE**

[mysql_ fetch_ assoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) function to get those values.

and one more thing: fetchin row will give you only numerical keys not associative keys.

and now ENJOY ;)

Comment: Removed "LOL" because that's actually pretty rude.